# Not getting output while creating hash of hashes

Tags: perl

I am trying to generate hash of hashes. I am reading the input from a txt file and converting the data into hash of hashes. Format of txt file is

```
flintstones : lead=fred pal=barney
jetsons : lead=george wife=jane "his boy"=elroy
simpsons : lead=homer wife=marge kid=bart
```

Hash of hashes format is as

```
%HoH = (
    flintstones => {
    lead      => "fred",
    pal       => "barney",
    },
    jetsons     => {
    lead      => "george",
    wife      => "jane",
    "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    simpsons    => {
    lead      => "homer",
    wife      => "marge",
    kid       => "bart",
},
 );
```

Code I am writing is

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ();
my $hash1 = {};
open (FH, "2.txt") or die "file not found";
while (<FH>) {
my @array = split (":", $_);
$array[0] =~ s/^\s*//;
$array[0] =~ s/\s*$//;
$array[1] =~ s/^\s*//;
$array[1] =~ s/\s*$//;
my @array1 = split (" ", $array[1]);
for (0..$#array1) {
    my ($key, $value) = split ("=", $array1[$_]);
    $hash{$array[0]}{$key} = $value;
    #$hash1->{$key} = $value;
    #print "    $hash1{$key} \n";
}
#$hash{$array[0]} = $%hash1;

}
close FH;
print " value is %hash" ;
```

Not getting output. What is wrong in my code

Comment: You loop using array indexes and then try to split the indexes instead of the array elements.

Comment: Can you tell me in code format. I am spliting the line after ":". Then i am left with "lead=fred pal=barney". Splitting with space and then splitting with "="

Comment: `for (0 ... $#array1)  .... split ("=", $_)`. That's not all that's wrong with your code, though. You split once without using a pattern, you split once and discard the result. You do not account for quoted whitespace in a key, leading to odd number of hash elements.

Comment: I have removed the leading and trailing spaces but still same issue. Following line i have added in the code: $array[0] =~ s/^\s*//;
 $array[0] =~ s/\s*$//;

Comment: @TLP: Need help in this. I am splitting based on space say "lead=fred wife=jane "his boy"=elroy" I dont want to split inside "his boy". How to skip this

Comment: @Nitesh you need to use `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%hash);` to print your data correctly

Comment: @Nitesh You might look into using the `Text::ParseWords` module to handle quoted whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# match chars or chars inside '"' following by '=' and chars for hash value
my $re = qr/(?: (\w+) | "(.+?)" ) = (\w+)/x;
my %hash;

open (FH, "<", "2.txt") or die $!;
while (<FH>) {
  my ($k, $s) = split /\s*:\s*/, $_, 2;
  my %hash1 = grep defined, $s =~ /$re/g;
  $hash{$k} = \%hash1;
}
close FH;

use Data::Dumper;
print "value is ", Dumper \%hash;
```